# Linq to XML doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm starting to understand this whole Linq to XML-stuff, however, I'm finding myself puzzled as why a certain query won't work as it's supposed to.

The error is clearly in the query but I can't find it. Maybe one of you can shed a light in the darkness.

This is my XML:

```
<folder title="test1" id="f6e27403" index="1">
<list index="1" name="content1" title="" id="5702f74a"></list>
<list index="2" name="content2" title="" id="a39db279"></list>
<list index="3" name="content3" title="" id="6f48a9e7"></list>
<list index="4" name="content4" title="" id="85d2823c"></list>
<list index="5" name="content5" title="" id="669d28f4">
    <theme index="1" name="Q1" type="r1theme" title="" id="6bf9dbce" created="2015-06-17 10:02:35" modified="2015-06-18 17:34:30">
    <properties>
        <field index="1" name="remark"/>
        <field index="2" name="title">SERIES A</field>
    </properties>
    <list>
        <theme index="1" name="q" type="lb" title="" id="b021319d-03ae-1c7a-ab31-fb081bae4570" created="2015-05-28 11:17:09" modified="2015-06-19 11:23:13">
            <properties>
                <field index="1" name="remark"/>
                <field index="2" name="content">Test</field>
            </properties>
            <list>
                <item index="1" name="q" type="item" title="" id="52ddcb77" created="2015-05-28 11:19:35" modified="2015-05-28 11:19:35">
                    <field index="1" name="query">content 1</field>
                    <field index="2" name="remark"/>
                </item>
                <item index="2" name="q" type="item" title="" id="2f5793db" created="2015-05-28 11:18:00" modified="2015-05-28 11:18:00">
                    <field index="1" name="query">content 2</field>
                    <field index="2" name="remark"/>
                </item>
            </list>
        </theme>
    </list>
    </theme>

    <theme index="2" name="Q2" type="r1theme" title="" id="6bf9dbce" created="2015-06-17 10:02:35" modified="2015-06-18 17:34:30">
    <properties>
        <field index="1" name="remark"/>
        <field index="2" name="title">SERIES B</field>
    </properties>
    <list>
        <theme index="1" name="q" type="lb" title="" id="ad703b7e" created="2015-05-28 11:17:09" modified="2015-06-19 11:23:13">
            <properties>
                <field index="1" name="remark"/>
                <field index="2" name="content">Test</field>
            </properties>
            <list>
                <item index="1" name="q" type="letterbingoitem" title="" id="8a4a5c65" created="2015-05-28 11:19:35" modified="2015-05-28 11:19:35">
                    <field index="1" name="query">content 3</field>
                    <field index="2" name="remark"/>
                </item>
                <item index="2" name="q" type="letterbingoitem" title="" id="597f9791" created="2015-05-28 11:18:00" modified="2015-05-28 11:18:00">
                    <field index="1" name="query">content 4</field>
                    <field index="2" name="remark"/>
                </item>
            </list>
        </theme>
    </list>
    </theme>
</list>
</folder>
```

I've shortened it a bit for readability and I'm only showing two items per list where there are actually dozens of items.

I'm trying to extract the fields in the items of theme with index 1 and index 2 separately.

For this I'm using this XML to LINQ-query:

```
int indexToSearchFor = 1;

var temp = xml.Descendants("list").Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "content5").Descendants("theme").Where(g => (string)g.Attribute("type") == "lb" && (string)g.Attribute("index") == indexToSearchFor.ToString()).Descendants("field").Where(x => x.Attribute("name") != null).Where(y => y.Attribute("name").Value == "query").Select(z => z.Value).ToList();
```

This query is basically a modification from another query that I'm using.

Now when I run this query, the resulting list contains all of the fields with the name "query", so content 1, content 2, content 3 and content 4 where as I'm only looking for the fields with the name "query" from the theme with type "lb" and index "1".

I need to process both the theme with index1 and index2 seperately so in my case that's not working. But I cannot seem to figure out why?

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While reading over my post again, I just spotted the mistake...

In my XML both the Themes with type "lb" have the same index. It's the parent theme which have different indexes, so I need to use those. So the amended code is:

```
var temp = xml.Descendants("list").Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "content5").Descendants("theme").Where(g => (string)g.Attribute("type") == "r1theme" && (string)g.Attribute("index") == indexToSearchFor.ToString()).Descendants("field").Where(x => x.Attribute("name") != null).Where(y => y.Attribute("name").Value == "query").Select(z => z.Value).ToList();
```